# Converting string to decimal, not working for some cases?

Tags: c, arrays, string

i am trying to take a string and seeing if it could be converted into decimal/float/octal/hex

I have stored these strings into an array, and im iterating through them and checking which element is what.

```
for(int k=0;k<i;k++){

    char* string = tokenArray[k];
    fprintf(newFile, "Tokens are: %s\n", string);


    if(checkDecimal(string) == 1){
        result[k] = "Decimal";      printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);
    }

    else if(checkFloat(string) == 1){
        result[k] = "Float";        printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);
    }

    else if(checkHex(string) == 1){
        result[k] = "Hex";      printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);

    }

    else if(checkOctal(string) == 1){
        result[k] = "Octal";        printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);

    }
    else {

        printf("Token: %s Did not work\n", string);        
    }
```

I wrote contents of my array into a separate file which is, :

```
       fprintf(newFile, "Tokens are: %s\n", string);
```

Tokens are: 012

Tokens are: 23948

Tokens are: 1.21e+19

Tokens are: [

Tokens are: ,

Tokens are: 0

Tokens are: 0x56

Tokens are: 888

Tokens are: 0X11

Tokens are: 12

Tokens are: 333

Tokens are: 234

Tokens are: 012

Tokens are: 12

Tokens are: 01200

As you can see i am getting the tokens correctly, but my output is coming up weird.

This is my code for checking elements:

```
int checkFloat(char *s){

char *str = NULL;
long i = strtol(s, &str, 0);

if (!*str)
    return 0;  


if (*str == 'e'  || *str == 'E'  ||  *str == '.')
    return 1;


return 0;  
         }




int checkHex(char *s){

char *str = s;

if((*str) == '0'){

    if((*(str++) == 'x')){
        printf("%s\n", "olala");
    }
}
if(*(str) == 0 && (*(str++) == 'x' || *(str++) == 'X'))
{
    printf("%s\n", "ok");
    while(*(str) != '\0')
    {
        if (!isxdigit(*str))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        ++str;
    }

    return 1;
}

return 0;
           } 



int checkOctal(char *s){

char *str = s;

if (*str != '0')
{
    return 0;
}


while (isdigit(*str) && *str != '8' && *str != '9')
{
    if(*(++str) == '\0')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    str++;
}

return 0;
         }




int checkDecimal(char *s){

char *str = s;

if(*str == '0')
    return 0;


    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){

        if(str[i] < 49 || str[i] > 57)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
           }
```

I think these functions are fine,

this is the output:

Token: 012 is Octal

Token: 23948 is Decimal

Token: 1.21e+19
 is Float

Token: [ Did not work

Token: , Did not work

Token: 0 is Octal

Token: 0x56 Did not work

Token: 888 is Decimal

Token: 0X11
 Did not work

Token: 12 is Decimal

Token: 333 is Decimal

Token: 234
 Did not work

Token: 012
 Did not work

Token: 12 is Decimal

Token: 01200 is Octal

As you can see, first token was 012 which came out as octal (fine). Another token with same 012 came out as error. Same with "234".

I dont know why my hex fucntion dosent work either.

Plz help

Comment: Please spend some time learning how to use a debugger first.

Comment: I'm not going to debug your code, but you could do that and see what happens. You will probably find the error. If the same number does not produce the same result, then probably you are not re-initializing your read pointer for each new line, and if 0x12 does not work, you are probably not advancing the read pointer where it should be, or you are advancing it where it shouldn't be. But you will have to find out by yourself, IMO. Use a good debugger.

Comment: Note: your hex code is convoluted. First check for `0x`or `0X`, then check the rest. Note that `0 != '0'`, but `0 == '\0'`.

Comment: I tried using debugger but this is not the main file, and it gives me error :                Undefined reference to main.

for hex function, i tried many things just dosent work!

Comment: Rather than `if(str[i] < 49 || str[i] > 57)`, try `if(str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9')`  They are not quite the same.

Comment: There is not enough here to re-create OP's issue - to much unposted code, missing inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: You may add another piece to the puzzle looking at `typeof` [**5.6 Referring to a Type with typeof**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Typeof.html). You would want to add a confirmation of the size of the object which in narrow cases can be done with `sizeof (typeof)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's most outstanding issue is your use of '++' (increment).  You tend to overuse it, skipping over characters you intend to test.  E.g. consider a clause like:

```
(*(str) == 0 && (*(str++) == 'x' || *(str++) == 'X'))
```

Which can leave the pointer in two different locations and fails to test for 'X' as it's looking at the wrong character.  This really should be:

```
(*str++ == '0' && (*str == 'x' || *str == 'X'))
```

Your code is riddled with this type of error.  (As well as confusing 0 with '0' as noted in the comments.)  Fixing your increments and generally reworking your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE } boolean;

int checkFloat(char *s) {
    char *extra = NULL;

    (void) strtol(s, &extra, 0);

    return ((*extra != '\0') && (*extra == 'e' || *extra == 'E' || *extra == '.'));  
}

int checkHex(char *s) {
    char *str = s;

    if (*str++ == '0' && (*str == 'x' || *str == 'X')) {

        while (*(++str) != '\0') {
            if (!isxdigit(*str)) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
} 

int checkOctal(char *s) {
    char *str = s;

    if (*str++ != '0') {
        return FALSE;
    }

    while (isdigit(*str) && *str != '8' && *str != '9') {
        if (*(++str) == '\0') {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int checkDecimal(char *s) {
    char *str = s;

    if (*str == '0') {
            return FALSE; // looks like octal
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] < '1' || str[i] > '9') {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

char *tokenArray[] = {
    "012",
    "12948",
    "1.21e+19",
    "[",
    ",",
    "0",
    "0x56",
    "888",
    "0X11",
    "12",
    "333",
    "234",
    "012",
    "12",
    "01200"
};

#define TOKEN_COUNT (sizeof(tokenArray) / sizeof(char *))

int main() {

    char *result[TOKEN_COUNT];

    for (size_t k = 0; k < TOKEN_COUNT; k++) {

        char *string = tokenArray[k];

        if (checkDecimal(string)) {
            result[k] = "Decimal";
            printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);
        } else if(checkFloat(string)) {
            result[k] = "Float";
            printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);
        } else if (checkHex(string)) {
            result[k] = "Hex";
            printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);
        } else if (checkOctal(string)) {
            result[k] = "Octal";
            printf("Token: %s is %s\n", string, result[k]);
        } else {
            printf("Token: %s Did not work\n", string);        
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Produces:**

```
Token: 012 is Octal
Token: 12948 is Decimal
Token: 1.21e+19 is Float
Token: [ Did not work
Token: , Did not work
Token: 0 Did not work
Token: 0x56 is Hex
Token: 888 is Decimal
Token: 0X11 is Hex
Token: 12 is Decimal
Token: 333 is Decimal
Token: 234 is Decimal
Token: 012 is Octal
Token: 12 is Decimal
Token: 01200 is Octal
```

In general, style-wise, you should pick an indentation/bracketing style you like and stick with it consistenly -- your code is all over the place.